# How do I loop a video in MPlayerX?

Tags: macos, software

I downloaded [MPlayerX](http://itunes.apple.com/app/mplayerx/id421131143?mt=12) from the App Store and I would like to use it to play a video in loop.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: About your "quality standards" question, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!!!

1. Open the MPlayerX Preferences window by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or via the menu 
   *MPlayerX → Preferences…*
2. Go to the *Advanced* tab in the Preferences window.
3. In the textfield with the label *Extra Options* enter `-loop n`, where `n` is the number of times you want to loop.

Comment: Strangely it isn't working for me now... MPlayerX automatically closes after one go. Anyone facing a similar situation?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a menu, preference option, or any mention on the [support page](http://mplayerx.org/) or change logs for a looping option, so I think it might be safe to say no, there isn't a way to do that with that piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method.

Open the video in MPlayerX and *pause* it. Drag the timeline slider to the desired starting point (keep it all the way left to start from the begginiing at time 0:00). Click *Playback* in the menubar > *A-B Loop* > *Set Start Point*.

Then, drag the timeline slider to the ending point (or all the way right if you want to loop the entire video). Go to *Playback* > *A-B Loop* > *Set Return Point*.

Now the video will keep looping between these 2 points.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Choose the video you want to watch. Open it and pause before playing.
Then click the button on the right most top and press play where u can find the loop option. Have fun

Comment: Can you add more explanation? I didn't find any loop option. And the `-loop n` would have a black screen.